# How to disable the mapping of Ctrl+; to underscore e in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I noticed that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> is somehow mapped to a strange mini-popup window with a `e` and underbar below it (Ubuntu 22.04). I wasn't sure what this is for, and want to disable the mapping as I need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> for something else. But I don't know where to change this. I don't have additional input methods installed other than English.

My `/etc/default/keyboard` is as follows:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

*What is this mapping to underscore e used for?*

*How can I disable it?*

Comment: E with an underline? That's likely emoji input, you're being prompted for further input to select the emoji (compare Ctrl-Shift-u starting a similar prompt with u instead of e, for Unicode input)

Comment: It's likely your DE - Gnome or whichever, or in your terminal emulator (if using one).  These allow key-mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this mapping to underscore e used for?

- This is the emoji selection panel/picker

To disable the command, run in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "@as []"
```

Useful link: [Ask Ubuntu: new ctrl-period key sequence default in 21.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372781/new-ctrl-period-key-sequence-default-in-21-10)